# sed to replace SECRET_KEY in django settings file, introduces garbage

Tags: sed

I built a small script that creates a copy from a standard django setup. After copying the project, I'd like to replace the `SECRET_KEY`. Both the original `SECRET_KEY` and the replacement contain numerous special characters. My shell code looks like this:

```
SECRET=$(python -c 'from random import choice; import sys; sys.stdout.write("".join([choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789^&*(-_=+)") for i in range(50)]))')
sed --in-place "s/^SECRET_KEY = .*/SECRET_KEY = '${SECRET}'/" src/settings.py
```

When I run this, it works sometimes, but in most cases the result looks something like this:

```
SECRET_KEY = '*n(hbp+o31v*d3pSECRET_KEY = '=ih8(6hwlqiamvg88_jtatqi1w2^axl=+omrpwck*aena-c3ax'8gpv8SECRET_KEY = '=ih8(6hwlqiamvg88_jtatqi1w2^axl=+omrpwck*aena-c3ax'8bwc4ele+bk(*+)vv4tSECRET_KEY = '=ih8(6hwlqiamvg88_jtatqi1w2^axl=+omrpwck*aena-c3ax'*qscez(f'
```

I have no idea where all this garbage comes from, but I guess it has something to do with the special characters in either the original `SECRET_KEY` or the replacement that are interpretet as regex special characters. Any  idea how I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do regex escaping of your secret generator, and you should be fine :

using re.escape.

```
SECRET=$(python -c 'import re;from random import choice; import sys; sys.stdout.write(re.escape("".join([choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789^&*(-_=+)") for i in range(50)])))')
```